# duplicate files in categories>documents

Tags: huawei

I have a Huawei GR5 2017 BLL-L22 cell phone running Android 7. There are duplicate files under Categories>Documents. For example, There are two "birthday 9-10.txt", both having the exact same date, time and file size. Another example: "18614_20190915 financial.xlsx". Again, same date, time, and file size. There are more.

The strange thing is if I delete the duplicate, leaving only one copy of them. Not before long, the duplicate comes back. I'm not using Cloud. I don't synchronize anything. Who or what is making the duplicate and how do I stop it?

Comment: Your media database (maintained by the Android Media Service app) seems to be corrupt. You can clear the app data of the Android Media Service to enforce the database to be built completely new.

Comment: I can't find that app on my cell phone.

Comment: This is a system app that is not visible in the launcher app menu. You have to open the Android settings and there the app list. On some devices you additionally have to select in the menu to show all applications including system apps.If you still don't find use [AppInspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01) and search for the app `com.android.providers.media`.

Comment: I opened: Settings>Apps. Couldn't find it. I then downloaded AppInspector and ran it. Still, did not see it. The closest thing I found is com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks. There is nothing else under com.android.providers.